# Create a hierarchical JSON Http response structure using LinQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to have a nested hierarchical JSON response from a ASP.NET webAPI where is defined a flat model based of a SQL table.

I'm new in ASP.NET WebAPIs. 
I've a MVC ASP.NET project where is definied an assembly Model Class. Each assembly can be a child of another assembly with theoretical infinite children and childrenOfchildren.

The Assembly Model Class linked to a SQL Table is defined like:

```
Int Id
String Name
Int ParentId
```

I need to perform a Http GET to retrieve the parent-child hierarchical structure.

Now I've the following function in the assembly controller class:

```
[Route("api/Assembly/GetTree/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Assembly> GetTree(int id)
{
    var assemblies = db.Assemblies.Where(x => x.ParentId == id || x.Id == id).ToList();
    var child = assemblies.AsEnumerable().Union(db.Assemblies.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ParentId == id).SelectMany(y => GetParent(y.Id))).ToList();

    return child;
}
```

The problem (i think) is that the "union" returns me a flat JSON response.

the db.Assembies is an instance of the db context model class assembly autogenerated from the db and defined as follow:

```
public partial class Assembly
    {
        public Assembly(){}

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

The expected result should be like:

```
[
    {
        Id: '1',
        Name: 'Assembly1',
        ParentId: '0'
        children: [
            {
                Id: '2',
                Name: 'Assembly1.1',
                ParentId: '1',
            },
            {
                Id: '3',
                Name: 'Assembly1.2',
                ParentId: '1',
            },
        ]
      }, 
      {
        Id: '4',
        Name: 'Assembly2',
        ParentId: '0'
        children: [
            {
                Id: '5',
                Name: 'Assembly2.1',
                ParentId: '4',
                children: [
                    {
                        Id: '6',
                        Name: 'Assembly2.1.1',
                        ParentId: '5',
                    },
                    {
                        Id: '7',
                        Name: 'Assembly2.1.2',
                        ParentId: '5',
                    },
                ]
            },  
            {
                Id: '8',
                Name: 'Assembly2.2',
                ParentId: '4'
                children: [
                    {
                        Id: '9',
                        Name: 'Assembly2.2.1',
                        ParentId: '8',
                    },
                    {
                        Id: '10',
                        Name: 'Assembly2.2.2',
                        ParentId: '8',
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

How can i put the assemblies one inside the others?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. on SO, people can help with clear programming issues, you tried A, you got result B, but you expected C. Not I want this, go write the code for me.

Comment: what is there under `db.Assemblies` please post that

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that the children aren't visible from the parent node. So serializing the parent, will just give the parent node. However if the parent stored all the children, then the serializing logic will be able to recurse through all the depended data and give you the nested hierarchy you're looking for.

Something akin to this:

```
void Main()
{
    var grandChild1 = new Node() { Name = "GrandChild1" };  
    var child1 = new Node() { Name = "Child1", Children = new List<Node> {grandChild1} };
    var child2 = new Node() { Name = "Child2" };    
    var root = new Node() { Name = "Root", Children = new List<Node> {child1, child2} };

    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);

    Console.WriteLine(serialized);
}

public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This would give the following output:

```
{
    "Name": "Root",
    "Children": [{
            "Name": "Child1",
            "Children": [{
                    "Name": "GrandChild1",
                    "Children": null
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "Name": "Child2",
            "Children": null
        }
    ]
}
```